# Is there spring data jpa implementation for MySqlDocument store just like MongoRepository for Mongo

Tags: spring-data

We can use MongoRepository available in spring data project as the Repository when using mongo db. Now i want to use MySqlDocumement store (MySql 8+) as the underlying document DB. Is there an equivalent Repository interface for MySqlDoc store in the spring data repository that extends the more generic CrudRepository?